# Syntax for jquery data element

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to pass two strings using ajax to code-behind method with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#updateMember').click(function () {
                var ar = $(this).closest('.details').prev('.heading').prop('id');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'team-members.aspx/UpdateTeamMember',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "ID": + ar + "," + "Name" + ":" + $('#tmname').val() }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: fnsuccesscallback,
                    error: fnerrorcallback,
                });
            });

            function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
                console(data);
                window.location.reload();
            }
            function fnerrorcallback(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I'm new to jquery and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I guess I'm using quotation marks wrongly, cause in the code-behind method I get correct value of the ID argument, and null for Name.

Name is argument who gets it's value from textbox with an ID='tmname' and ID is getting value from a variable ar, as it's shown in the code.

Does someone knows what I'm going wrong with Name argument?

Comment: correct syntax is like data: JSON.stringify{ID: ar , Name: $('#tmname').val()},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSON.stringify({ "ID":  ar,"Name":$('#tmname').val() }),
```

This should do it. Since you are creating an object on the go and not doing string concatenation, you need not use '+' to create a JSON string. `JSON.stringify` will gladly do that for you.

Answer (score 3):

Just change this line

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "ID": + ar + "," + "Name" + ":" + $('#tmname').val() }),
```

To this...

```
data: {ID: ar ,Name: $('#tmname').val() },
```

Or this...

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "ID": ar, "Name": $('#tmname').val() }),
```

On an unrelated note, Im pretty sure you also need to include the data in the function calls, to actually pass the data from the ajax call to the functions.  I could be wrong though

```
dataType: "json",
success: fnsuccesscallback(data),
error: fnerrorcallback(result),
```

Or..

```
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){ fnsuccesscallback(data)},
error: function(result){ fnerrorcallback(result)},
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've tried it like that at the begging but it goes straight to error function. consol.log says: Invalid JSON primitive: ID. @KyleK

Comment: it's working now Vikram's answer helped :) Thanks once again :)

Comment: I'm not sure but this might cause a problem if you've variables named as `ID` or `Name`.

Answer (score 2):

You Should Just Use JSON Directly For Data Attribute And Keep It In Your Mind Every Index Present A Value That Will Be Send.
Also You Should Define Your Function First And Then Use It As A Listener.
Change Your Code To It And Try Again:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
                console(data);
                window.location.reload();
            }

            function fnerrorcallback(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }

            $('#updateMember').click(function () {
                var ar = $(this).closest('.details').prev('.heading').prop('id');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'team-members.aspx/UpdateTeamMember',
                    data: { "ID":  ar,"Name":$('#tmname').val()},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: fnsuccesscallback,
                    error: fnerrorcallback,
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do Like This:

var name=$('#tmname').val();

var data={"ID":ar,"Name":name}

data:JSON.stringify(data);